# I need help width the Random code

Tags: java, random, int

I need help width the `Random r = new Random();` code.

I will give you my code and tell you what I want to do.

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.nextInt(3);
System.out.println(i);

//now how do i make it not to take 0 as a random number
//One of them is 0, how do i make it take a random int that is
//bigger than 0 but lower than 3. I need help there.
```

Comment: `r.nextInt(2) + 1` ?

Comment: Did you do the slightest bit of research before posting this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, think about it. You currently get 0, 1, or 2. So how could you get just 1 or 2? You pass `2` into `nextInt` so you get either `0` or `1`, and add `1` to the result:

```
int i = r.nextInt(2) + 1;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, It works perfectly.

Comment: probably shouldn't encourage questions with no research effort, and guide to duplicate post instead

Comment: @Maljam: I saw the dupe and dupehammered, thanks for finding it. Re answering: I saw a teachable moment and took it. :-)